# implicit value for evidence parameter when iterating

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, akka, parquet, alpakka

My task is to get tables from jdbc ant put them to s3. I have generated classes of these tables with Slick schema code generator.
If I write code manually for every table it works perfectly.
Like that

```
Slick
  .source(Tables.table1.result)
  .runWith(ParquetStreams.toParquetSingleFile(s"s3a://bucket/table1"))
  .onComplete {
    case _ =>
      println("table1")
  }
Slick
  .source(Tables.table2.result)
  .runWith(ParquetStreams.toParquetSingleFile(s"s3a://bucket/table2"))
  .onComplete {
    case _ =>
      println("table2")
  }
```

Problem is that I have a lot of tables and it will be easier if I could just iterate them.

Code

```
val tbls = Map("table1" -> Tables.table1, "table2" -> Tables.table2)
tbls.foreach(table => {
  val table_name = table._1
  Slick
    .source(table_2.result)
    .runWith(ParquetStreams.toParquetSingleFile(s"s3a://bucket/$table_name"))
    .onComplete {
      case _ =>
        println(table_name)
    }
})
```

Getting this error.

```
could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type com.github.mjakubowski84.parquet4s.ParquetRecordEncoder[_1#TableElementType]
[error]       .runWith(ParquetStreams.toParquetSingleFile(s"s3a://bucket/$table_name"))
```

**Edit: ------------------------------------------------------------**

Thank you for clarifying things. But even with suggestions it doesn't work. After applying those things same error exists and few more appear.

```
found   : slick.lifted.TableQuery[_1] where type _1 >: Tables.TableTwo with Tables.TableOne <: Tables.profile.Table[_ >: Tables.TableTwoRow with Tables.TableOneRow <: Product with java.io.Serializable]
```

Leaving simplified code here as someone asked.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp

import akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors
import akka.stream.alpakka.slick.javadsl.SlickSession
import akka.stream.alpakka.slick.scaladsl.Slick

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.{Await, ExecutionContext}
import com.github.mjakubowski84.parquet4s.{ParquetRecordEncoder, ParquetSchemaResolver, ParquetStreams}

object Tables extends {
  val profile = slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile
} with Tables

/** Slick data model trait for extension, choice of backend or usage in the cake pattern. (Make sure to initialize this late.) */
trait Tables {
  val profile: slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile
  import profile.api._

  case class TableOneRow(id: Int, values: Option[String] = None)
  class TableOne(_tableTag: Tag) extends profile.api.Table[TableOneRow](_tableTag, Some("schema"), "table_one") {
    def * = (id, values) <> (TableOneRow.tupled, TableOneRow.unapply)

    val id: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("id", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
    val values: Rep[Option[String]] = column[Option[String]]("values", O.Default(None))
  }
  lazy val TableOne = new TableQuery(tag => new TableOne(tag))

  case class TableTwoRow(id: Int, values: Option[Timestamp] = None)
  class TableTwo(_tableTag: Tag) extends profile.api.Table[TableTwoRow](_tableTag, Some("schema"), "table_two") {
    def * = (id, date) <> (TableTwoRow.tupled, TableTwoRow.unapply)

    val id: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("id", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
    val date: Rep[Option[Timestamp]] = column[Option[Timestamp]]("date", O.Default(None))
  }
  lazy val TableTwo = new TableQuery(tag => new TableTwo(tag))
}

object Main extends App {

  implicit val actorSystem: ActorSystem[Nothing] = ActorSystem(Behaviors.empty, "alpakka-sample")
  implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext = actorSystem.executionContext
  implicit val session = SlickSession.forConfig("slick-mysql") // (1)

  import session.profile.api._

  case class TableWithRecordEncoder[A](
    table: TableQuery[A])(
    implicit val recordEncoder: ParquetRecordEncoder[A]
  )

  def doTheThings[A](table: TableWithRecordEncoder[A], path: String) = {
    import table.recordEncoder
    Slick
      .source(table.table.result)
      .runWith(ParquetStreams.toParquetSingleFile(path))
      .onComplete {
        case _ =>
          println("Done. " + path)
      }
  }

  import polymorphic._
  def withRecordEncoder[A](table: TableQuery[A])(implicit recordEncoder: ParquetRecordEncoder[A])
  : Exists[TableWithRecordEncoder]
  = Exists(TableWithRecordEncoder(table))

  import polymorphic.syntax.all._
  Map("s3a://bucket/table_1" -> withRecordEncoder(Tables.TableOne),
     "s3a://bucket/table_2" -> withRecordEncoder(Tables.TableTwo)).
     foreach{ case (path, table) =>
      doTheThings(table.value, path)
    }

  actorSystem.whenTerminated.map(_ => session.close())
  Await.result(actorSystem.whenTerminated, Duration.Inf)

}
```

Comment: Can you post complete source code files? If the first example compiles, then there must be an implicit value in scope in that example that is no longer in scope after refactoring. If you've extracted a method, you probably need to add an implicit parameter to it.

Comment: On second look, I think it’s a problem inferring the types, because when you add them to the map, it loses the concrete type of each table value and widens to the super type. Then there’s most likely no generic encoder defined for that super type.

Answer (score 3):

When you put `Tables.table1` and `Tables.table2` into a collection, the compiler will find the least upper bound of their types, let's call it `T`. `T` will be the `Map`'s value type. But implicit search is performed at compile time, and there is no suitable `ParquetRecordEncoder` instance for `T#TableElementType`, only for the concrete subtypes.

Therefore, if you want to iterate over these, you need to add not only the tables to the map, but also all relevant type class instances.

//edit: this is actually a bit tricky, so I've prepared an example for how this could work. I hope you can work it out from here.

To make things easier I'm using the [polymorphic](https://github.com/alexknvl/polymorphic) library.

So you have the `Table` and `ParquetRecordEncoder` types that look something like this:

```
trait Table[A] // details omitted
trait ParquetRecordEncoder[A]
```

And we need some instances to play with:

```
val intTable = new Table[Int] {}
val stringTable = new Table[String] {}
object ParquetRecordEncoder {
  implicit val int = new ParquetRecordEncoder[Int] {}
  implicit val string = new ParquetRecordEncoder[String] {}
}
```

Now we need a type to package those two together:

```scala
case class TableWithRecordEncoder[A](
  table: Table[A])(
  implicit val recordEncoder: ParquetRecordEncoder[A]
)
```

And we need a function that will do something useful with such objects:

```scala
  def doTheThings[A](table: TableWithRecordEncoder[A]) = {
    import table.recordEncoder // now we have a ParquetRecordEncoder[A]
                               // available as an implicit!

    ???                        // logic goes here
  }
```

But since the type parameter `A` is going to be different for  each table, we can't stuff different `TableWithRecordEncoder` objects into the same `Map`! This is where the `Exists[F[_]]` type from the `polymorphic` library comes in. It squashes all those different types down to one. Let's define a little helper to make such objects:

```scala
import polymorphic._
def withRecordEncoder[A](table: Table[A])(implicit recordEncoder: ParquetRecordEncoder[A])
  : Exists[TableWithRecordEncoder]
  = Exists(TableWithRecordEncoder(table))
```

Note that the table's element type doesn't appear at all in the return type of `withRecordEncoder`. No matter what the table's element type is, the function will always return an `Exists[TableWithRecordEncoder]`! This is crucial, because now we can stuff different tables in the same map:

```scala
import polymorphic.syntax.all._
  Map(
    "int" -> withRecordEncoder(intTable),
    "string" -> withRecordEncoder(stringTable)
  ).foreach { case (name, table) =>
    doTheThings(table.value)
  }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Returned to this case after some time. I have tried to create ParquetRecordEncoder object, but its limited by 3rd part library and have methods in trait. Can I create this in other way? Link to this object https://github.com/mjakubowski84/parquet4s/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/com/github/mjakubowski84/parquet4s/ParquetRecordEncoder.scala

Comment: There's no point in discussing this without the code. Make a new question that shows what you've tried and where it fails.